# Entity Framework to EF Core 6 migration query not working

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

We are migrating our ASP.NET Framework Web Api project to .NET 6 and after fixing all build errors while running the project it starts giving errors in EF queries related to EF Core 3.0+ does not support client evaluation anywhere in the query. We have so many queries written in this way and it's very difficult to find and tell what part of query is causing the issue, like its left join using DefaultIfEmpty() or something else.

Is there some way or tool which can convert these queries to EF Core 3.0+ or at least tell exactly what part of query is causing the problem so that we can apply the change ASAP? Any help/idea will be appreciated, below is such query and I am getting client evaluation error but no clue what part is causing the error. I have all foreign keys constraints in database and I don't like to rewrite the queries again and test it.

```
var employees = (from e in context.Employees
     join c in context.CompanyEmployees on e.UserId equals c.EmployeeId into ec
     from ce in ec.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join cp in context.CompanyPositions
     on ce.Employee.UserId equals cp.UserId into cpgrp
     from cp1 in cpgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join ctp in context.CategoryPositions on cp1.PositionId equals ctp.PositionId into catpgrp
     from catp in catpgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where e.OrganizationId == organizationId && (companyId == null || ce.CompanyId == companyId)
     && (categoryId == null || catp.CategoryId == categoryId)
    
     select new { e, ce }).GroupBy(e => e.e.UserId).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: No tool.  Ef Core 3.x do not support such quirks with `GroupBy`. Search all group by queries.

Comment: Such query, which selects first element of the group, supported only from EF Core 6.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Thanks for replying but I am already using EF Core 6

Comment: If it does not work, so EF Core is still have limited support of such queries. I can propose workaround if you don't mind.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Yes, you are propose workaround and that will help a lot but I want to know from where we will came to know that what is not supported in EF Core 3.x+, means how you know that Ef Core 3.x do not support such quirks with GroupBy, can you share link to such documentation.

Comment: It is just not supported, a lot of things are not supported and I don't think it should be documented. From SQL side this query has no direct translation and EF Core lowers version has no functionality to simulate. Search "EF Core GroupBy First"

Comment: I know about these limitations because answering for 3 years of the same questions and because I also writing LINQ translator for `linq2db` and I know how it is hard to do such translation.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I appreciate the information but my main concern for documentation is that Microsoft has given a path to migrate from Entity Framework to EF Core 6 and there are many people like us who are getting such issues with queries and we are not responsible for doing translation of queries, Microsoft allows us to write queries in that way since years and now when we upgrade then no good documentation. If I go to this page https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client, it does not tell me enough.

Comment: I know SQL, and I would never write such LINQ query, this is my common sense. Also comparing EF Core 3.x vs EF Core 6 is also bad idea. A lot of limitations are solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246766/discussion-between-chupchapcharli-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).

Answer (score 1):

This is workaround query which should return desired result. It emulates what EF Core should do to correctly execute query from question.

```cs
var dataQuery = 
    from e in context.Employees
    join c in context.CompanyEmployees on e.UserId equals c.EmployeeId into ec
    from ce in ec.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join cp in context.CompanyPositions on ce.Employee.UserId equals cp.UserId into cpgrp
    from cp1 in cpgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join ctp in context.CategoryPositions on cp1.PositionId equals ctp.PositionId into catpgrp
    from catp in catpgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where e.OrganizationId == organizationId && (companyId == null || ce.CompanyId == companyId)
        && (categoryId == null || catp.CategoryId == categoryId) 
    select new { e, ce };

var query = 
    from d in dataQuery.Select(d => new { d.e.UserId }).Distinct()
    from q in dataQuery.Where(q => q.e.UserId == d.UserId)
        .Take(1)
    select q;
```

Note that usually joins are not needed because of navigation properties and such GroupBy query is a sign that something wrong with joins and query duplicates result.